# Checking is a string is binary

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a python programming challenge that requires a program for checking if a string is binary. If the string is binary, it should return "`true`". Otherwise, it should return "`false`".

When I ran the code, it iterates through the string and prints either "`true`" or "`false`" depending on whether the value in the string is "`0`" and "`1`" or not. Even though I have tried a couple of methods I keep ending up with a vertical display of the boolean values.

```
binary = {'0', '1'}
def is_binary(string):
    for i in str(string):
        if i in binary:
            print('true')
        else:
            print('false')
            break
is_binary('101010')
is_binary('101210')
```

How can I modify the code to be able to print a single "`true`" statement when the string is binary and a single "`false`" statement when the string is not binary regardless of the length of the string?

Comment: **Don't *print*, but *return***. Go through the string, if a digit is non binary, `return False`. If you reached the end of the string, it means that all digits are binary, hence `return True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do something like this:

```
def is_binary(str):
    is_binary = True
    try:
        int(str, 2)
    except ValueError:
        is_binary = False
    return is_binary


is_binary('0101010101010') # returns True
is_binary('24340101041042101010') # returns False
```

I have use `int` to convert to binary, [Please refer here to learn](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#int)

Comment: Thank you very much. I added a print statement when calling the function and I got exactly what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are printing if every character was in `binary` set which is NOT what you want. You want to print `true` only if all the characters were in `binary`. So, you only need to `print('true')` at the end of the `for` loop.

So, This should do it:

```
binary = {'0', '1'}
def is_binary(string):
    for i in str(string):
        if i not in binary:
            print('false')
            return
    print('true')
is_binary('101010')
is_binary('101210')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
def is_binary(bin_str):
    if (set(bin_str) - set(['1','0'])):
        return False
    else:
        return True

bin_str = "0110011"
print is_binary(bin_str)

bin_str = "011020"
print is_binary(bin_str)
```

**Output:**

```
True
False
```

**Solution using OP's logic:**

```
binary = {'0', '1'} 
def is_binary(string): 
    for i in str(string): 
        if i in binary: 
            continue 
        else: 
            return False 
    return True

print is_binary('101010') 
print is_binary('101210')
```

Comment: is_binary = lambda x: not bool(set(x) - {'0', '1'})

Comment: The Solution using OP's logic has helped me see where I was missing the point. I appreciate

Comment: Please consider upvoting, if the answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Short way

I stumble here and thought about this:

```
# Declare one true and one false vars
bb = '010010111010010001011100'
bb2 = '010010111010010001O11100' # there's a letter O here

bin_set = set('0','1') # A set with char '0' and char '1'
```

I also could have written `bin_set = {'0','1'}`

Then (I was in ipython 3):

```
In : set(bb) == bin_set
Out: True

In : set(bb2) == bin_set
Out: False
```

If a string is only composed with `0` and `1` then its `set()` will be equal to `{'0','1'}` (`set` representation in python)

hth